# Iterate through json object array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. In my Controller file, I have JSON containing an array (as a result of calling different API's):

```
{
    "Specialities": [{
        "SpecialityID": 1,
        "SpecialityName": "Eye Doctor"
    },{
        "SpecialityID": 2,
        "SpecialityName": "Chiropractor"
    },{
        "SpecialityID": 3,
        "SpecialityName": "Primary Care Doctor"
    }] 
}
```

In controller, I wrote

```
echo $response[0];
```

with this line of code I can easily iterate through json object in jquery:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/rest_project/main/res',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function (data){
        $.each(data.Specialities,function(key,value){
            console.log(value.SpecialityName);
        });
    }  
});
```

but if I pass the array:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then I am unable to get the results:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/rest_project/main/res',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function (data){
        $.each(data[0].Specialities,function(key,value){
            console.log(value.SpecialityName);
        });
    }
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your jsonObject is not an array and `each` works with array only.

```
//Check if your jsonObject is array, if not then make it.
if (!$.isArray(jsonObject)) {
    jsonObject = [jsonObject];
}

$.each(jsonObject, function(key, value){
  console.log("FULL NAME " + value.FullName);
});
```

```js
var data = {
    "Specialities": [{
        "SpecialityID": 1,
        "SpecialityName": "Eye Doctor"
    },{
        "SpecialityID": 2,
        "SpecialityName": "Chiropractor"
    },{
        "SpecialityID": 3,
        "SpecialityName": "Primary Care Doctor"
    }] 
};
//Convert your jsonObject to array for each
if (!$.isArray(data)) {
    data = [data];
}
$.each(data[0].Specialities,function(key,value){
   console.log(value.SpecialityName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```